# Subscribing to a ReactiveAsyncCommand is not calling OnError on thrown exception

Tags: reactiveui

I have created a ReactiveAsyncCommand (SL5) and have not been able to get a subscription to fire the OnError method. Here is the code

```
        Start1Command = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
        Start1Command.RegisterAsyncObservable(_ => this.Start())
            .Subscribe<int>(
                u => Debug.WriteLine("OnNext-->" + u.ToString()),
                ex => Debug.WriteLine("OnError-->" + ex.Message),
                () => Debug.WriteLine("OnComplete-->")
            );
        Start1Command.Execute(null);
```

And the code for Start

```
 public IObservable<int> Start()
 {
     return Observable.Start(() =>
         {
            throw new Exception("Exception");
            return 42;
         },
         RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler);
 }
```

When I run this code I get an exception from the ReactiveUI framework which suggests I should subscribe to ThrownExceptions. When I do, the exception I throw above is handled correctly.

```
 Start1Command.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => Debug.WriteLine("ThrownExceptions OnNext-->" + ex.Message));
```

Should I have expected that the command subscription would call OnError? or do I have to use ThrownExceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, your expectation is totally right. However, `RegisterAsync*` effectively intercepts `OnError`. This makes it easier to program against `RegisterAsync`, since once you handled the `OnError` once, in the `Subscribe`, it would never work again. Handling the `ThrownExceptions` means that you don't need to deal with resubscribing.

If that doesn't make sense, don't worry about it, just handle `ThrownExceptions` and assume the Subscribe only receives `OnNext`

Comment: Is it the expected behaviour that I must both subscribe to the command's ThrownExceptions *and* specify an OnError lambda in the RegisterAsyncTask().Subscribe()?  If I omit the OnError lambda (which would be empty in my case anyway), right after the ThrownExceptions handler executes and returns, the exception is thrown on the UI thread (in a context where I can't catch it).  If both are specified, both get executed and the exception is not thrown on UI thread.

Comment: It might currently be the expected behavior, but that expected behavior sucks. Can you file a bug?